# Screen capture as stream over LAN

Tags: lan, streaming, desktop-recording

I'm searching for a solution to capture my desktop and output it as a live stream for clients in a local network. I already tried ffmpeg and VLC, but the results were that it was not a live-stream.  It became a kind of recording that always started from the beginning when trying to watch.

I'm trying my luck now with WebcamStudio, but I haven't had any success yet.

Does anyone know a solution for my problem?

Answer (score 0):

for live stream you can use TeamViewer also . In my opinion its good tool for Live desktop streaming .

http://www.teamviewer.com/hi/download/dyngate.aspx